# How to add rounded corner to Blazorise card image?

Tags: css, image, blazorise

I'm using Blazorise Bulma card component, code like this:

```css
.infobox {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<Card Class="infobox">
    <CardImage Source="/assets/images/gallery/9.jpg" Alt="Placeholder image">
    </CardImage>
    <CardBody>
        <CardTitle Size="5">Card title</CardTitle>
        <CardText>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
        </CardText>
        <Button Color="Color.Primary">Button</Button>
    </CardBody>
</Card>
```

I cannot seem to add a border-radius to the whole card? The `infobox` class only adds rounded border to the bottom 2 corners. In order to add border-radius to the top 2 corners, I need to access the `image` element, but `CardImage` only has attributes `source` and `alt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a border then apply border-radius.I have also used **display:flex;**.You can also use a different background color to the card from the body instead of applying a border.Also, use  instead of **source**. If you need anything else, please let me know.

```css
.infobox {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
}

.image img{
width:200px;
border-top-left-radius:20px;
border-top-right-radius:20px;

}

.cardtitle{

text-align:center;

}

.btn{
display:flex;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<Card Class="infobox">
<div class="image"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png" Alt="Placeholder image"/>
    </div>
    <CardBody>
        <h4 class="cardtitle" Size="5">Card title</h4>
        <CardText>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
        </CardText>
        <Button class="btn" Color="Color.Primary">Button</Button>
    </CardBody>
</Card>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it does not solve my problem, in my question there is an image which needs to have top left and right rounded corners. Your answer does not have an image.

Comment: Also you don't need a border to set up a rounded corner with border-radius

Comment: Okay.The image source you have defined is local.That's why it's not loading here.You can copy this code and apply your own image src and test this code.In this case, border-radius was not working without a border.Maybe that's because of width and height was not applied.

Comment: I have updated my answer.Please check now.I have added a test image.Scroll down after running the snippet to see the full card body.

Comment: Thanks for your update, I think in order to accept your answer you'll need to improve it. The `image` element style is accessible through `.image img{ }`, and adding a border is not needed.

Comment: I have updated the answer as you want.I have Removed the border.Used background-color instead of border.Also, the image style is accessible through .image img{ }.If you like my answer, please upvote :)